# Criteria Builder Convert Lower different variant

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Everywhere I look I see people using this

```
predicate = 
    criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(Product_.prodName)), 
                         wrapper.getProdName());
```

especially I mean this `Product_.prodName`. I have no idea what it is, what it does and why I can't use or have it in my context. Here my code which not works:

Look at the line with !nachname.isEmpty

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Telefonbuch> query = builder.createQuery(Telefonbuch.class);
        Root<Telefonbuch> root = query.from(Telefonbuch.class);

        EntityType<Telefonbuch> model = em.getMetamodel().entity(Telefonbuch.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (!vorname.isEmpty()) {   
            Predicate condition = builder.like(root.<String>get("vorname"),"%"+vorname+"%");
            predicates.add(condition);
        }
        if (!nachname.isEmpty()) {
            Predicate condition = builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("nachname"),"%"+nachname+"%"));
            predicates.add(condition);
        }

        query.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        eintraege = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: If you dont know what "Product_" means then you really ought to read documentation about the API you are using. Look up JPA static metamodel. Ample links on the web

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I still don't unterstand fully what it does, but it works.